# Pansharpening problem in ArcGIS: failure when using TOA calibrated Landsat

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, pansharpening

I'm hoping to use the "Create pansharpen raster dataset" tool in ArcGIS to pansharpen Landsat 7/8 images. This tool works nicely and produces the expected pansharpened image when the input is in DN form. However, when I input TOA reflectance values (both multispectral and pan) instead of DN's, the function fails, and produces an all 0 tiff.

Does anyone know why that would happen?

Answer (score 1):

TOA reflectance is a float value and the tool that you are using only works with integers.

May I suggest that you use the tools available in QGis instead, which are capable of dealing with both formats.